# Help regarding basic questions on span?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

I am a bit rusty on Vector Spaces;
please verify my answers to the following questions:

## 1.

Let $V=\mathbb R^4$ and $v_1=(2,0,3,1), v_2=(2,3,0,1), v_3=(2,1,2,1)$.
Does $v=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in span(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ if $x_1=2x_4,x_3=-x_2+3x_4$?

Solution Outline: $v=(2x_4,x_2,-x_2+3x_4,x_4)=x_4(2,0,3,1)+x_2(0,1,-1,0)$
So if I show that both $(2,0,3,1)$ and $(0,1,-1,0)$ belong to $span(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, then I am done — is that right? Notice that $(2,0,3,1)=v_1$

## 2.

Basis for $W=\{a+(a+b)x+(2a+b)x^2+bx^3| \; a,b\in \mathbb R\}$

if $\alpha\in W\Rightarrow \text{For some a,b in R} \; \alpha = a+(a+b)x+(2a+b)+bx^3 = a(1+x+2x^2) +b(x+x^2+x^3)$

Hence $W=span(1+x+2x^2,x+x^2+x^3)$, which are also linearly independent, so this is the required basis.

## 3.

Is $Span(\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2},\frac{1-i\sqrt3}{2}) = Span(1,\sqrt3
)$ over $\mathbb R $ and $\mathbb C$?

According to me, Over $\mathbb R$, we basically want to check if $Span((\frac12,\frac{\sqrt3}{2}),(\frac12,\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2})) = Span((1,0),(\sqrt3,0))$, which is true.

Over $\mathbb C$, I don't think $\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}$ belongs to $Span(1,\sqrt3
)$, so they can't be equal. Does this makes sense?

Comment: I think you have (3) exactly backwards.

Comment: @GerryMyerson backward in the sense? Sorry I don't get you

Comment: In the sense that the spans are equal over the complex numbers, but not over the reals. But we may not be interpreting the question the same way. Somehow, you are interpreting the complex number $\alpha=(1+i\sqrt3)/2$ to be the real vector $(1/2,\sqrt3/2)$. OK, but then how are you interpreting $\alpha$ over the complex numbers?

Comment: Over the complex numbers, I am interpreting $\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ to be a single number. Over $R$, it is like a coordinate $(\frac12,\frac{\sqrt(3)}{2})$

Comment: I'd like to see the exact statement of the problem.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: @GerryMyerson this is the exact problem that appeared in my reference book

Comment: @GerryMyerson after looking again, I agree I got confused between the two. Over $R$, certainly $\frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ will not belong in the span of $\{(1,0),(\sqrt{3},0)\}$. Only on $C$, it would be possible

Comment: I'm very surprised to learn that this is the exact way the questions appear in a book. "Span" applies to *sets*, so I would expect in any book to see Span$\{a,b\}$, not Span$(a,b)$.